# Problem doing multiplication tables with while function

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a new programmer and this is my first question here so excuse me if its pretty easy.
M doing a multiplication table but each time it stops after the 1 and it doesnt increment the number

I am trying to do it with 2 while loops

```
nb = 1
i = 0
while nb<10 :
    while i<=10 :
        print(nb * i)
        i+=1
    nb+=1
```

with that code I only have the 1 multiplication table then the program stops

Comment: I get a printout from 0 to 10, so not sure why you don't.

Comment: @JackFleeting, OP is trying to get multiplication table for 1 through 9; not just for 1.

Comment: @Austin - Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset variable inside loop. Variable `i` reaches its max value after the first iteration of inner loop, which we need to set back to 0 for the next iteration to work:

```
nb = 1
while nb < 10 :
    i = 0
    while i <= 10 :
        print(nb * i)
        i += 1
    nb += 1
```

You can do the same using `for`, which in my opinion is more readable and you don't need to worry about incrementing/resetting variables:

```
for x in range(1, 10):
    for y in range(11):
        print(x * y)
```